# Widows-and-orphans with customized section

Tags: widows-orphans

With the help of the community here I found a solution for customized `sections` with a subtitle. TeX seems to apply some extensive processing on the `section`-title about how to handle page breaks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10,final]{microtype} % have some better layout of individual chars
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for highlighting AND background images-color!!!
%\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow} % prevents orphans and widows
\usepackage{widows-and-orphans}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec} % to have the section NOT justify, i.e. the lines can be shorter (for linebreak)
\usepackage{keyval}
% Set formats for each heading level
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{gray}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{gray}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{gray}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*3}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*3}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*3}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\define@key{chk}{subtitle}{\def\chk@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\sectionLvl[3][]{%
{   \setkeys{chk}{subtitle={},#1}%
    \normalsize\bfseries\color{gray}%required for deeper level
    \ifcase#2\relax\expandafter\chapter\or%section
    \relax\expandafter\section\or%subsection
    \relax\expandafter\subsection\or%subsubsection
    \expandafter\subsubsection
    \fi
    [#3]{#3%check if subtitle exists
        \ifx\chk@subtitle\@empty\relax\else%add subtitle
        \nopagebreak\endgraf\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
        \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
            \raggedright\normalfont\sffamily%font of subtitel
            \textcolor{gray}{\chk@subtitle}%subtitle itself
        }\endgraf\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
        \fi%end of subtitle
    }
}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
 \sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle}]{1}{first Kant}
 \kant[1-3]
 \vspace{4.5cm}
\sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle}]{1}{second Kant}
 \kant[1-4]
sectionLvl[subtitle={Test Subtitle}]{1}{third Kant}
\kant[1-4]

\end{document}
```

With my above solution I have now the issue that the `section` (with its subtitle) will be a widow.  [image]

If I want to prevent this I guess I need to use a package. I searched for hints how to prevent widows and found two main packages: `nowidow` and `widows-and-orphans`.  With `widows-and-orphans` I didn't succeed. While `nowidow` seems quite old it is working (by using `defaultlines=3` and an additional `\nopagebreak`). The side effect is that I have now 3 line as minimum.

Is there a way to stick to the minimum of 2 lines and still prevent some unwanted page breaks?

Comment: widows and orphans are not relevant here, they are breaks *inside* a paragraph, your break is *between* paragraphs. You need `\nobreak` and `\@afterheading` in the right place.

Comment: Aha... thx for clarification. I think the option `nobottomtitles*` from the `titelsec` packages helps. Although its not working with this sample it works in my use case. Thank you for pointing in a direction.